# Magento : Same Product Adds to Different Line in Cart

Tags: magento-1.9, product, addtocart

If user adds product to cart without logging in and then logs in, if same product is available in user's cart which was added to his cart in his earlier logged in session, product shows in same line instead of updating the quantity. I tried disabling local modules and switching to rwd theme. Still the issue exists. Magento version is 1.9.2.2

Answer (score 0):

The issue got fixed by enabling **Persistent Shopping Cart**.